# Does it make sense to prefer jsonb data type over text[] even if I am only planning to store text array?

Tags: postgresql

I am thinking from the perspective that (I believe) `jsonb` is more efficient and can get indexed more easily.

Comment: I would decide this based on the type of queries that will be needed. Some things can't be done with jsonb and some things can't be done with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

There is no advantage in using a JSON type for a plain array, but I guess there is no big disadvantage either. Keep it simple and use `text[]`.

Comment: For context, I was wondering if jsonb would produce better performance for typical checks, like checking if array contains value, than GIN index.

Comment: No, it should be about the same.